# How to add regular Java resource folder in different module to Android module in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have a project in Android Studio with two modules. One is a regular Java module and the other is an Android app module.

The regular Java module has plain text files located in `src/main/resources`. I want to read these text files in my Android app module. Is there a way to have the app module add these resources as Android assets or do I need to manually copy them over into the app module's assets folder?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to!

Be sure to add in your gradle file compile project(:'custom_module') in your app module that wants access, and then you can import the module as Resource. Import the R. in your code, and use getResources() to get to your strings.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear in the original formatting of my question. The strings in the Java module aren't in an Android resources xml file, they are text files which I want to read in the app module into `String` objects.